# Use awk to find all columns which contain values above and below specified numbers?

Tags: awk

I would like an Awk command where I can search a large file for columns which contain numbers both **below 3** and **above 5**. It also needs to skip the first column.

e.g. for the following file

```
   1 2 6 2
   2 1 7 3
   3 2 5 4
   4 2 8 7
   5 2 6 8
   6 1 9 9
```

In this case, only column 4 is a match, as it is the only column with values above 5 and below 3 (except for column 1, which we skip).

Currently, I have this code:

```
 awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i < 3 && $i > 5) {print i}}}'
```

But this only reads one row at a time (so never makes a match). I want to search all of the rows, but I am unable to work out how this is done.

Ideally the output would simply be the column number. So for this example, simply '4'.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please add expected output sample too in code tags and let me know then?

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 I have added a brief line. Just the column number would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i<3){col[i]++};if($i>5){col1[i]++}}} END{for(j in col){if(col[j]>=1 && col1[j]>=1){print j}}}'  Input_file
```

If you want to start searching from second column then change `i=1` to `i=2` in above code.

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i<3)                   {  col[i]++ };
    if($i>5)                   {  col1[i]++}}
}
END{
  for(j in col){
    if(col[j]>=1 && col1[j]>=1){  print j  }}
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted an awk command which only prints the column number if in the entire column there are both numbers above 5 and below 3. so the output for the above example would simply be: "4", for the 4th column.

Comment: @birac, but 4th column's second line is NOT lesser than 3 it is equal so is it a valid case if any value is lesser than or equal to 3 and any value is greater than or equal to 5 for columns, please confirm?

Comment: The 4th column matches the requirement as it has values below 3 (i.e. row 1) and values above 5 (rows 4,5 and 6). As long as *somewhere* in the column both requirements are met, it's a match.

Comment: @birac, sure please check my EDIT now, in case you want to skip column 1st then use `i=2` in my code, let me know then?

Comment: wionderful! Thanks :-)